# Encounter some JNI warning but I didn't use JNI in my Android App

Tags: android, sockets, java-native-interface, printwriter

In my android app, Logcat printed some warning about JNI, but I didn't use any JNI code, only used Socket to get server data. Here is the warning:

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026): ReferenceTable overflow (max=1024)

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026): JNI pinned array reference table (0x6b551a80) dump:

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):   Last 10 entries (of 1024)

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):      1023: 0x43605f90 byte[] (8192 elements)

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):      1022: 0x42ed7488 char[] (1 elements)

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):      1021: 0x41892580 byte[] (8192 elements)

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):      1020: 0x4194d4a0 byte[] (8192 elements)

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):      1019: 0x4423eb70 byte[] (8192 elements)

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):      1018: 0x4434d598 byte[] (8192 elements)

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):      1017: 0x4412d258 byte[] (8192 elements)

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):      1016: 0x440bee80 byte[] (8192 elements)

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):      1015: 0x44075330 byte[] (8192 elements)

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):      1014: 0x43fd3338 byte[] (8192 elements)

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):   Summary:

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):      1023 of byte[] (8192 elements) (1023 unique instances)

12-30 16:49:11.100: W/dalvikvm(8026):         1 of char[] (1 elements)

12-30 16:49:11.100: E/dalvikvm(8026): Failed adding to JNI pinned array ref table (1024 entries)

12-30 16:49:11.100: I/dalvikvm(8026): "Thread-13341" prio=5 tid=1045 RUNNABLE

12-30 16:49:11.100: I/dalvikvm(8026):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x42963498 self=0x6d1038b0

12-30 16:49:11.100: I/dalvikvm(8026):   | sysTid=1784 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1829780736

12-30 16:49:11.100: I/dalvikvm(8026):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1

12-30 16:49:11.100: I/dalvikvm(8026):   at libcore.icu.NativeConverter.encode(Native Method)

12-30 16:49:11.110: I/dalvikvm(8026):   at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoderICU.encodeLoop(CharsetEncoderICU.java:167)

12-30 16:49:11.110: I/dalvikvm(8026):   at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:415)

12-30 16:49:11.110: I/dalvikvm(8026):   at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.convert(OutputStreamWriter.java:178)

12-30 16:49:11.110: I/dalvikvm(8026):   at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:266)

12-30 16:49:11.110: I/dalvikvm(8026):   at java.io.PrintWriter.doWrite(PrintWriter.java:623)

12-30 16:49:11.110: I/dalvikvm(8026):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:601)

12-30 16:49:11.110: I/dalvikvm(8026):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:579)

12-30 16:49:11.110: I/dalvikvm(8026):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:641)

12-30 16:49:11.110: I/dalvikvm(8026):   at java.io.PrintWriter.print(PrintWriter.java:453)

12-30 16:49:11.110: I/dalvikvm(8026):   at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:549)

12-30 16:49:11.110: I/dalvikvm(8026):   at com.sivotech.killgame.SocketClient.sendMsg(SocketClient.java:31)

12-30 16:49:11.110: I/dalvikvm(8026):   at com.sivotech.killgame.Game3_2Activity$11$1.run(Game3_2Activity.java:980)

12-30 16:49:11.110: E/dalvikvm(8026): VM aborting

12-30 16:49:11.110: A/libc(8026): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 1784 (Thread-13341)

12-30 16:49:11.160: I/DEBUG(1255): *****  ** *****  ** *****  ** *****  ** *****  ** ***

12-30 16:49:11.160: I/DEBUG(1255): Build fingerprint: 'TECLAST/fiber_q8s/fiber-q8s:4.2.2/JDQ39/20131022:eng/test-keys'

12-30 16:49:11.160: I/DEBUG(1255): Revision: '0'

12-30 16:49:11.160: I/DEBUG(1255): pid: 8026, tid: 1784, name: Thread-13341  >>> com.sivotech.killgame <<<

12-30 16:49:11.180: I/DEBUG(1255): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 deadd00d  r3 00000000

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     r4 408911b0  r5 0000020c  r6 00000000  r7 40891518

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     r8 6d2e0008  r9 42ed7498  sl 1d20000d  fp 1d200009

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     ip 00004000  sp acd99978  lr 400ec219  pc 40828c90  cpsr 60000030

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     d0  74726f6261204d56  d1  2e7974697669746e

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     d2  746341325f336575  d3  313124797469766c

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     d4  4342e43043304680  d5  435ab13043475b10

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     d6  4383dc20437572b8  d7  439864c843920240

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     d8  c1c0000000000000  d9  461c400000001b0d

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     d10 00000000435d6666  d11 0000000000000000

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     d16 4000000000000000  d17 4010000000000000

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     d18 3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f  d19 0000000000000000

12-30 16:49:11.610: I/DEBUG(1255):     d20 3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f  d21 202020203d3d3d3d

Maybe it's the PrintWriter's problem?